# How can Terraform 0.11.10 or 0.11.7 ignore a single tag

Tags: terraform

To better improve change analysis and debugging I want to add a 'ModifiedAt' tag to terraform managed AWS resources without creating a lot of noise and churn when plans are applied.

I can ignore all tag changes and so I only modify when there's a substantive change to the resource.  However, I really only want to control for the **ModifiedAt**, **ModifiedByJob**, **ModifiedByCommit**, **ModifiedByUser** tags as they change based on source control, date and build server not due to code changes.

**Ignore All Tags**

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["tag"]
 }
```

**Should but doesn't ignore specific tags**

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["tags.ModifiedAt", "tag.ModifiedAt", 
        "tags[ModifiedAt]", "tags['ModifiedAt'"]
 }
```

**Providers**

- "null" (1.0.0)...
- "tls" (1.2.0)...
- "aws" (1.52.0)...
- "template" (1.0.0)...
- "local" (1.1.0)...

I'm not sure what's wrong.  According to [issue 6632](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6632) at least one of these should work but they do not for me.

Comment: Your comment from the issue (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6632#issuecomment-447437408) works for me to ignore some tags but track others. Perhaps something else is happening or I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need the following, to ignore the 4x tag names you have listed:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "tags.%", # the count of tag keys, which may change also
      "tags.ModifiedAt",
      "tags.ModifiedByJob",
      "tags.ModifiedByCommit",
      "tags.ModifiedByUser"
    ]
  }
```